# What is this large tree with many suckers growing from the trunk?

Tags: identification, trees

Can anyone help me identify the following tree? It has large leaves and a number of new sections (suckers) growing from the trunk.

Any help would be gratefully received.

*Note: This may be a similar (or identical) species to another tree I am trying to identify. See [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22074/help-identifying-tree-species-1-of-3*) question.

[image: Tree]

[image: Leaves]

[image: Trunk]

Answer (score 7):

This is [Tilia americana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilia_americana) or the American Linden or the basswood. This large tree is native to North America and grows quickly to as much as 120 feet tall.

Although it has many [good characteristics](http://landscapeontario.com/tilia-americana-basswood):

- adaptable: shade to full sun, wet to dry soil
- some tolerance to salt
- transplants well
- few pests

This tree is not used much in urban settings due to it's large size.  Your picture also shows one of the less known traits of the species: the tendency to sucker or bud from old wood.

The flowers are attractive to bees and wasps and when we had a relative planted it tended to drop seed pods, leaf sheathes and other debris constantly.  A good tree to plant at some distance from your house or driveway.

As Michelle points out in North American it is also subject to attack by Japanese beetles.  If you have roses, grapes or Virginia creeper they can attract the beetles who then settle in to defoliate your tree.

Comment: ...or as a street tree, if you ask the urban foresters in my area. ;) One additional trait to consider: they are very attractive to Japanese Beetles and in a banner year for beetles can be nearly defoliated. Luckily, in my experience they do bounce back the next year.

Answer (score 2):

Tilia platyphyllos judging by the size of its leaves (around 16mm across, but variable, sometimes larger)- very common in and around London, but not so common as the European Lime, or Tilia x europaea - leaves on that around 10cm across - not sure which it is, not being there to measure up, but the latter tree commonly produces these shoots from the bole or trunk.